# How to divide two values from the same column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

As the title states I would like to divide two values with each other that are in the same column. 
E.g.

```
    A             B              C            D
  Shirts         2011           85            0
  Shirts         2012           92      percent change from 2011 to 2012
  Shirts         2013          100      percent change from 2012 to 2013
  Pants          2011           31            0
  Pants          2012           42      percent change from 2011 to 2012
  Pants          2013           55      percent change from 2012 to 2013
  Jacket         2011           10            0
  Jacket         2012           16      percent change from 2011 to 2012
  Jacket         2013           18      percent change from 2012 to 2013
```

In this example column D would be a derived from column C, where the value of 2012 is subtracted from 2011, and then times by a 100 to get the percent.

I don't know how to set the query up I tried doing a bunch of sub-queries but didn't know how to link them together. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I were you, I will do it outside SQL, e.g. do the logic in PHP.

Comment: You can not do it with Simple Sql, either you have to use Stored procedure/Functions in Database or a server side language to implement the Business Logic

Comment: @AdamPlocher sql server 2008 r2

Comment: @PiyasDe A self-join in SQL will accomplish this for the OP; a stored procedure or function is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option to get what you're after

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c,
    CASE WHEN t2.c IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE t1.c - t2.c END AS d,
    CASE WHEN t2.c IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE (1.0 * t1.c - t2.c) / t1.c * 100.0 END AS pct
FROM t t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t t2 ON t1.a = t2.a
    AND t1.b = t2.b + 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fbab/22)

Comment: I have a quick question you entered +1 at the end on the t2.b column and I was just wondering what that was for?

Comment: That is how it joins one row to another.  So, a t1.b value matches the value of t2.b + 1, or 2011 = 2010 + 1.  t1 is the 2011 row and t2 is the 2010 row.

Comment: hey @bobs sorry to bother so much i am pretty new to SQL so still learning all the ropes. I wrote the following SQL and got a column value for PCT as all 0's, any help?
SELECT
 a.FiscalYear
, a.Dx_Group
,a.TotalAppnts_NEW
,a.TotalAppnts_RETURN
,case when b.TotalAppnts_NEW IS null Then 0 else ((b.TotalAppnts_NEW-a.TotalAppnts_NEW)/a.TotalAppnts_NEW)*100 End PCT
From 
ONC.tTEMP_ORCM_Visits as A LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT 
 b.FiscalYear
, b.Dx_Group
,b.TotalAppnts_NEW
,b.TotalAppnts_RETURN
From
ONC.tTEMP_ORCM_Visits b)
B on a.Dx_Group=b.dx_group and a.FiscalYear=b.fiscalyear+1

Comment: ohh god that looks so bad i tried putting each sentence of the select statement on a different line

Comment: Since you get 0, I assume that b.TotalAppnts_NEW is null.  But, you may want to include b.TotalAppnts_NEW as a new column just to see what the value is.  If the b.TotalAppnts_NEW column is always null, you may want to focus on the the subquery that is aliased to B. Just with a brief glance, your query seems to be fine.

Comment: once again i am sorry too keep bothering, there are a few values in the totalappnts_new that are null, but out of almost 70 rows of data only about 7 or 8 are null all the rest hold values.

Comment: The problem may be that the query is doing integer math, where the result of dividing an integer by an integer is an integer.  When doing integer math, 1/2 is not 0.5; it's 0.  I included "1.0 *" in my answer (1.0 * t1.c - t2.c) to force it to floating point math.  You can try that or add a CAST function (e.g., CAST (t1.c AS DECIMAL(10, 2)).  The CAST is probably better because it's more explicit.

Comment: I hate that I have to cast everything that's one thing I always forget to do. thanks so much man this worked flawlessly how do I give you credit for this

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  You can click up-arrow to vote all answers that are good.  And, click check mark on answer that is your choice as best.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, you could use a recursive cte to accomplish your results.  This uses `ROW_NUMBER()` and partitions by (groups by) column A.

*This method would best work if you can't guarantee sequential years in column B. If you always have sequential years, then bobs provides the best alternative.*

```
with cte as (
  select A, B, C, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY B) rn
  from yourtable
  ),
recursive_cte as (
  select A, B, C, 0 prc
  from cte
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select y.A, y.B, y.C, y.C-c.C prc
  from cte y 
    join cte c on y.a=c.a and y.rn=c.rn+1
)
select * 
from recursive_cte
order by a, b
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/399ba/1)

This will return the difference between each year and the previous grouped by column A.  It uses a 2nd CTE just for simplicity.  If you want the actual percent changed, update the formula above.

***--EDIT***

Since it sounds like you're looking for percentage growth, try replacing y.C-c.C prc with this formula instead:

```
cast(y.C as decimal(10,2))/cast(c.C as decimal(10,2))
```

Use `CAST` if your data types are integers.

Comment: thanks sgeddes i will try this tomorrow, i have a quick question, CTE is that a another word for sub query?

Comment: @user2167857 -- yep, just easier than rewriting :)  Depends on your needs -- this will work well if years aren't necessarily sequential (2011-2013) for example.  If however they are always guaranteed to be sequential, there are easier alternatives (bobs provides one for example).  Just depends on your needs.  Best of luck.

Comment: thanks for your help, I really do appreciate it, as you said bobs answer worked best for me, though i really do appreciate you taking the time out to help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with a self-join:

```
SELECT curr.ClothingType, curr.SalesYear, curr.NumberSold
   , COALESCE((CAST((curr.NumberSold - prev.NumberSold) AS NUMERIC(5,2)) / prev.NumberSold) * 100, 0) AS PercentChange
FROM #Clothes AS curr
LEFT JOIN #Clothes AS prev ON curr.ClothingType = prev.ClothingType
   AND curr.SalesYear = prev.SalesYear + 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6af1/2/0)

Comment: I tried your way and I keep getting 0's as an outcome for the computation part I am adding the SQL I wrote can you let me know if there is something I am doing wrong. thanks for your help               SELECT
 a.FiscalYear
, a.Dx_Group
,a.TotalAppnts_NEW
,a.TotalAppnts_RETURN
,case when b.TotalAppnts_NEW IS not null and a.TotalAppnts_NEW IS not null Then ((b.TotalAppnts_NEW-a.TotalAppnts_NEW)/a.TotalAppnts_NEW)*100 ELSE 0 End PCT
From 
ONC.tTEMP_ORCM_Visits as A LEFT OUTER JOIN
ONC.tTEMP_ORCM_Visits as B on a.Dx_Group=b.Dx_Group
and a.FiscalYear=b.FiscalYear+1

Comment: @user2167857 Your columns are likely integers, and your query will result in integer division, removing the fraction (percent).  Note my `CAST( AS NUMERIC(5,2))` which will turn the numerator into a `NUMERIC` value, allowing the calculations to persist the percent values you are looking for.

Comment: Wegner Thanks man your and Bob's answer is almost exactly the same I appreciate all the help.

Comment: @user2167857 You're welcome - I'm glad you got your problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Shivan, but only because I don't know how to do it without PHP.  With PHP it's just a matter of pulling the two totals, doing the math and sending a query back with the answers.

**ALSO BE SURE TO READ THIS BECAUSE IT'S THE MORE IMPORTANT PART**
Your math's wrong.  `(Shirts2011 - Shirts2012) * 100` doesn't give you the percent change.  It just gives you `100 times the difference of the two` (actually, the negative difference based on your wording).  What you want, math-wise, is:

```
((Item2012-Item2011)/Item2011)*100
```

I know the outside parens aren't necessary but they make it easier to read.  The percent change is the same as 100 times the ratio of the difference of the two to the initial.

*Edited to add PHP code.*

The PHP looks gross, but it gets the job done.

```
$conn = new PDO(HOST:DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    $query = "SELECT A, B, C FROM yourTable";
    $st = $conn->prepare($query);
    $st->execute();

$list = array();
while($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $list[] = $row;

$fill = array();
for($i=1; $i<count($list); $i++)
    if($list[$i]['A'] == $list[$i-1][A])
        $fill[] = $array('A' => $list[$i]['A'],
                         'B' => $list[$i]['B'],
                         'D' => ($list[$i]['C']-$list[$i-1]['C'])/$list[$i-1]['C']*100);

$update = new PDO(HOST:DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    for($i=0; $i<count($fill); $i++){
        $query = "UPDATE yourTable SET D = " . $fill[$i]['D'] . " WHERE A = " . $fill[$i]['A'] . " AND B = " . $fill[$i]['B'];
        $st = $update->prepare($query);
        $st->execute();
    }
```

Just initialize your table where the 2011 D columns = 0.

```
UPDATE yourTable SET D = 0 WHERE B = 2011;
```

And before the flames start, I know a foreach would have worked; I just think a standard for looks better (and allows you to skip the first 2011 value).

Comment: lol i know the formula just got lazy writing it out, i thought the more important part was trying to figure out how to divide two values that are in the same column. i apologize if it does make a difference though. Also im not familiar with PHP i havent used it before. I will try aiias' solution tomorrow, but in the mean time anyone have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.type A, t1.year B, t1.value C,
IF(
  EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t1.type = t2.type AND t1.year = (t2.year - 1)
  ),
  ((SELECT t3.year FROM table t3 WHERE t1.type = t3.type AND t1.year = (t3.year - 1)) - t1.year)/t1.year,
  0
) D
FROM table t1
```

Not super efficient, but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Y2013.*, Y2012.C, Y2013.C, Y2013.C/Y2011.C
from (
  select * from data where B = year(getdate())
) Y2013
left join (
  select * from data where B = year(getdate()) - 1
) Y2012 on Y2012.A = Y2013.A
left join (
  select * from data where B = year(getdate()) - 2
) Y2011 on Y2011.A = Y2012.A
 and  Y2011.A = Y2013.A
```

Comment: i was thinking of doing it this way however this would be put into an SSIS package and then dumped into a table, to be used going forward, so next year 2014 will be added and 2011 will be gone

Comment: @user2167857: How careless of me; check now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this too:

```
UPDATE mytable t1
  INNER JOIN mytable t2 
  ON t1.A = t2.A AND t2.B = t1.B - 1
SET t1.D = ((t1.C - t2.C)  / t2.C) * 100;
```

see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbb43/1/0).

Assuming you already have 0 as a default for D. If not, just set it to 0 for all rows before running this query.